# trouble with a ajax filter, quick view is not working for filtered product

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

here i putting the codes of my java script files and html structure.
the products quick view modal working till i do not use filter but when i select something to filter it stop working.

```js
//product fiter start
$(document).ready(function() {
    function showValues() {
  $("#productContainer").css("opacity",0.5);
  $("#loaderID").css("opacity",1);
  
  //e.css('visibility','visible');
  
    
  var mainarray = new Array();
  
  var brandarray = new Array();  
  $('input[name="bcheck"]:checked').each(function(){   
   brandarray.push($(this).val());  
   $('.spanbrandcls').css('visibility','visible');   
   //alert($(this).attr("checkboxname")); 
  });
  if(brandarray=='') $('.spanbrandcls').css('visibility','hidden');
  var brand_checklist = "&bcheck="+brandarray;
    
  var sizearray = new Array();  
  $('input[name="scheck"]:checked').each(function(){   
   sizearray.push($(this).val()); 
   $('.spansizecls').css('visibility','visible'); 
  });
  if(sizearray=='') $('.spansizecls').css('visibility','hidden');
  var size_checklist = "&scheck="+sizearray;
  
  
  var colorarray = new Array();  
  $('input[name="ccheck"]:checked').each(function(){   
   colorarray.push($(this).val());
   $('.spancolorcls').css('visibility','visible');  
  });
  if(colorarray=='') $('.spancolorcls').css('visibility','hidden');
  var color_checklist = "&ccheck="+colorarray;
  
  
  var pricearray = new Array();  
  $('input[name="price_range"]:checked').each(function(){   
   pricearray.push($(this).val());
   $('.spanpricecls').css('visibility','visible');  
  });
  if(pricearray=='') $('.spanpricecls').css('visibility','hidden');
  var price_checklist = "&price_range="+pricearray;
  
  var main_string = brand_checklist+size_checklist+color_checklist+price_checklist;
  main_string = main_string.substring(1, main_string.length)
  //alert(main_string);
  
  
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "filter_products1.php",
   data: main_string, 
   cache: false,
   success: function(html){
    //alert(html);
    $("#productContainer").html(html);  
    $("#productContainer").css("opacity",1);
    $("#loaderID").css("opacity",0);
    
    
    
   }
   });
  
  
 }
 
 $("input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']").on( "click", showValues );
    $("select").on( "change", showValues );
 
 
 $(".spanbrandcls").click(function(){
  $('.bcheck').removeAttr('checked');    
  showValues();
  $('.spanbrandcls').css('visibility','hidden');
 });
 $(".spansizecls").click(function(){
  $('.scheck').removeAttr('checked'); 
  showValues();
  $('.spansizecls').css('visibility','hidden');
 });
 $(".spancolorcls").click(function(){
  $('.ccheck').removeAttr('checked'); showValues();
  $('.spancolorcls').css('visibility','hidden');
 });
 $(".spanpricecls").click(function(){
  $('.price_range').removeAttr('checked'); showValues();
  $('.spanpricecls').css('visibility','hidden');
 });
 $(".clear_filters").click(function(){
  $('#productCategoryLeftPanel').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
  $('#productCategoryLeftPanel').find('input[type=radio]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
  showValues();
 });
 
}); 
//product fiter ends here
//Quick view

//----Include-Function----
function include(url){ 
 "use strict";
 document.write('<script src="'+ url + '" type="text/javascript"></script>'); 
}


include('twitter/jquery.tweet.js'); // Twitter widget */
include('js/tinynav.min.js'); // Tiny nav



$(document).ready(function(){
 "use strict";
 
 
 var windowWidth = $(window).width();
 var windowHeight = $(window).height();
 
 
 
 /* Quick View */
 quickViewModal($('a.product-hover'));
 
 
 
 /* Functions */
 dropdownsNavigation(); // DropDowns
 
 searchBar(); // Search Bar
 
 selectBox(); // Select Boxes (Chosen plugin)
 
 backToTop(); // Back to top arrow
 
 backToTopEvent(); // Initialize back to top event
 
 tabsOn(); // Turn Tabs On
 
 accordionsOn(); // Turn Accordions On
 
 fixNavigation(); // Fix Main Navigation
 
 fixGridView(); // Fix Category Grid View
 
 installCarousels(); // Install Owl Carousels
 
 installNoUiSlider(); // Installs noUi Slider
 
 singleProduct(); // Cloud Zoom
 
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Window Scroll */
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  
  backToTop(); // Back to top
    
 });
 
 
 
 /* Window Resize */
 $(window).resize(function(){
 
  // Set the new Window Width and Height
  windowWidth = $(window).width();
  windowHeight = $(window).height();
  
  
  fixNavigation(); // Fix Main Navigation
  
  fixGridView(); // Fix Category Grid View
  
  fixRevolutionArrows(); // Fix Revolution Sliders Arrows
  
  
 });
 
 
 
 
 /* Twitter WIdget */
 $('#twitter-widget').tweet({
  modpath: 'twitter/',
  count: 2,
  loading_text: 'loading twitter feed...',
 })
 
 
 
 
 /* Tooltips */
 $('.tooltip-hover').tooltip();
 
 
 
 
 // TinyNav.js 1
 $('#main-navigation>ul').tinyNav({
  active: 'current-item',
  header: 'Navigation',
  indent: '→',
  label: 'Menu'
 });
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Revolutions Slider */
 jQuery('.tp-banner').revolution({
  delay:9000,
  startwidth:1170,
  startheight:500,
  hideThumbs:10,
  navigationType:"none"
 });
 
 
 
 
 /* IOS Slider */
 $('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
  scrollbar: true,
  snapToChildren: true,
  desktopClickDrag: true,
  scrollbarMargin: '5px 40px 0 40px',
  scrollbarBorderRadius: 0,
  scrollbarHeight: '2px',
  navPrevSelector: $('.prevButton'),
  navNextSelector: $('.nextButton')
 });
 
 
 
 
 
 /* FlexSlider */
 $('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  prevText: "",           
  nextText: "",
  start: function(slider){
   $('body').removeClass('loading');
   }
 });
 
 /* Sidebar Flexslider */
 $('.sidebar-flexslider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: true,
  directionNav: false,
  prevText: "",           
  nextText: "",
  start: function(slider){
   $('body').removeClass('loading');
   }
 });
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Rating */
 
 // Read Only
 $('.rating.readonly-rating').raty({ 
  readOnly: true,
  path:'js/img',
  score: function() {
   return $(this).attr('data-score');
  }
  });
  
 // Rate
 $('.rating.rate').raty({ 
  path:'js/img',
  score: function() {
   return $(this).attr('data-score');
  }
 });
 
 
 
 
 /* Fix Revolution Slider Arrows */
 function fixRevolutionArrows() {
  
  $('.tp-banner').each(function(){
   
   setTimeout(function(){
   
    var arrow_l = $('.tp-banner').find('.tp-leftarrow');
    var arrow_r = $('.tp-banner').find('.tp-rightarrow');
    
    var tp_height = $('.tp-banner').height();
    var arrow_height = $(arrow_l).height();
    var arrow_top = (tp_height/2)-(arrow_height/2);
    
    
    $(arrow_l).css('top', arrow_top);
    $(arrow_r).css('top', arrow_top);
    
   },1000);
   
  });
 
 }
 
 
 
 
 /* Navigation Height Fix */
 function fixNavigation(){
  
  var nav = $('#main-navigation>ul>li');
  $(nav).find('>a').attr('style', '');
  var nav_height = $(nav).height();
  
  $(nav).each(function(){
  
   $(this).find('>a').innerHeight(nav_height);
   
  });
 
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Product Grid View */
 function fixGridView(){
  
  if($('.grid-view').length>0){
   
   $('.grid-view.product .product-content').attr('style', '');
   
   var product_height = $('.grid-view.product img').height();
   var previous_height = $('.grid-view.product .product-content').innerHeight();
   
   if(previous_height < product_height){
    $('.grid-view.product .product-content').innerHeight(product_height);
   }
  }
  
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Single Product Page */
 function singleProduct(){
 
  
  /* Product Images Carousel */
  $('#product-carousel').flexslider({
   animation: "slide",
   controlNav: false,
   animationLoop: false,
   directionNav: false,
   slideshow: false,
   itemWidth: 80,
   itemMargin: 0,
   start: function(slider){
   
    setActive($('#product-carousel li:first-child img'));
    slider.find('.right-arrow').click(function(){
     slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("next"));
    });
    
    slider.find('.left-arrow').click(function(){
     slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("prev"));
    });
    
    slider.find('img').click(function(){
     var large = $(this).attr('data-large');
     setActive($(this));
     $('#product-slider img').fadeOut(300, changeImg(large, $('#product-slider img')));
     $('#product-slider a.fullscreen-button').attr('href', large);
    });
    
    function changeImg(large, element){
     var element = element;
     var large = large;
     setTimeout(function(){ startF()},300);
     function startF(){
      element.attr('src', large)
      element.attr('data-large', large)
      element.fadeIn(300);
     }
     
    }
    
    function setActive(el){
     var element = el;
     $('#product-carousel img').removeClass('active-item');
     element.addClass('active-item');
    }
    
   }
   
  });
   
   
  
  /* FullScreen Button */
  $('a.fullscreen-button').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var target = $(this).attr('href');
   $('#product-carousel a.fancybox[href="'+target+'"]').trigger('click');
  });
  
  
  /* Cloud Zoom */
  $(".cloud-zoom").imagezoomsl({
   zoomrange: [3, 3]
  });
  
  
  /* FancyBox */
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
  
  
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Set Carousels */
 function installCarousels(){
  
  $('.owl-carousel').each(function(){
  
   /* Max items counting */
   var max_items = $(this).attr('data-max-items');
   var tablet_items = max_items;
   if(max_items > 1){
    tablet_items = max_items - 1;
   }
   var mobile_items = 1;
   
   
   /* Install Owl Carousel */
   $(this).owlCarousel({
    
    items:max_items,
    pagination : false,
    itemsDesktop : [1199,max_items],
    itemsDesktopSmall : [1000,max_items],
    itemsTablet: [920,tablet_items],
    itemsMobile: [560,mobile_items],
   });
  
   
   var owl = $(this).data('owlCarousel');
   
   /* Arrow next */
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.icon-left-dir').click(function(e){
    owl.prev();
   });
   
   /* Arrow previous */
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.icon-right-dir').click(function(e){
    owl.next(); 
   });
   
  });
  
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 /* No UI Slider */
 function installNoUiSlider(){
  
  if($('.noUiSlider').length > 0){
  
   var min_val = $('.noUiSlider').attr('data-min-value');
   var max_val = $('.noUiSlider').attr('data-max-value');
   var min_range = $('.noUiSlider').attr('data-min-range');
   var max_range = $('.noUiSlider').attr('data-max-range');
   
   $('.noUiSlider').noUiSlider({
     range: [min_range,max_range]
    ,start: [min_val,max_val]
    ,connect: true
    ,slide: function(){
     var noui_val = $('.noUiSlider').val();
     $('.price-range-min').text('$'+noui_val[0]);
     $('.price-range-max').text('$'+noui_val[1]);
    }
   });
   
   var noui_val = $('.noUiSlider').val();
   $('.price-range-min').text('$'+noui_val[0]);
   $('.price-range-max').text('$'+noui_val[1]);
  
  }
  
 } 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Product Actions Accordion */
 var productButtons = $('.product-actions').not('.full-width');
 productButtons.find('>span:first-child').addClass('current');
 
 productButtons.find('>span').hover(function(){
  
  $(this).parent().find('>span').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
  
 }, function(){
  
  $(this).removeClass('current');
  
 });
 
 productButtons.hover(function(){
  
 }, function(){
  $(this).find('>span:first-child').addClass('current');
 });
 
 
 
 
 
 /* NAVIGATION DROPDOWN EFFECTS */
 function dropdownsNavigation(){
  
  var mainNav = $('#main-navigation');
  var mainNavItems = $('#main-navigation>ul>li');
  var sideNavItems = $('.sidebar-box-content>ul>li');
  
  
  mainNav.find('ul.normalAnimation').removeClass('normalAnimation');
  
  
  /* Navigation FadeIn Dropdown Effect */
  mainNavItems.hover(function(){
   
   var dropdown = $(this).find('>ul');
   if(!dropdown.hasClass('animating') && windowWidth>767){
    
    dropdown.css('opacity',0).css('top','150%').show().animate({opacity:1, top:100+'%'},300);
    
   }
   
  }, function(){
   
   var dropdown = $(this).find('>ul');
   if(!dropdown.hasClass('animating')){
    
    dropdown.addClass('animating').animate({opacity:0, top:150+'%'},300, function(){
     $(this).hide().removeClass('animating');; 
    });
    
   }
   
  });
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  /* Navigation SlideDown Dropdown Effect */
  sideNavItems.hover(function(){
   
   var dropdown = $(this).find('>ul');
   if(!dropdown.hasClass('animating') && windowWidth>767){
    
    dropdown.hide().fadeIn(200);
   }
   
  }, function(){
   
   var dropdown = $(this).find('>ul');
   if(!dropdown.hasClass('animating')){
    $(this).find('>ul').addClass('animating').show().fadeOut(100, function(){
     $(this).removeClass('animating'); 
    });
   }
   
  });
  
  
  
  
  
  
  /* Navigation Fadein Dropdown Effect 2 */
  mainNav.find('ul.normal-dropdown>li').hover(function(){
   
   var dropdown = $(this).find('>ul');
   if(!dropdown.hasClass('animating') && windowWidth>767){
    
    dropdown.hide().fadeIn(200);
   }
   
  }, function(){
   
   var dropdown = $(this).find('>ul');
   if(!dropdown.hasClass('animating')){
    $(this).find('>ul').addClass('animating').show().fadeOut(100, function(){
     $(this).removeClass('animating'); 
    });
   }
   
  }); 
  
  
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Search BAR */
 function searchBar(){
  
  
  /* SearchBar Fadein Effect */
  var searchButton, searchBar;
  
  searchButton = $('.nav-search');
  searchBar = $('#search-bar');
  
  searchButton.click(function(){
   
   if(searchBar.hasClass('searchbar-visible')){
    searchButton.removeClass('searchbar-visible');
    searchBar.animate({opacity:0, left:-200, right:200},200, function(){
     $(this).removeClass('searchbar-visible').hide();
    });
   }else{
    searchButton.addClass('searchbar-visible');
    searchBar.css('opacity', 0).css('left', -200).css('right',200).show().animate({opacity:1, left:0, right:1},300, function(){
     $(this).addClass('searchbar-visible');
     var config = {
      '.chosen-select-search' : {disable_search_threshold:10, width:'100%'}
     }
     for (var selector in config) {
       $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
     }
    });
   }
   
  });
  
  
  
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Back to top button */
 function backToTop(){
  
  var button = $('#back-to-top');
  var w_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  
  if(w_scroll > 150  && windowWidth>767){
   button.fadeIn(400); 
  }else{
   button.fadeOut(400); 
  }
  
 }
 
 
 /* Back to top button event */
 function backToTopEvent(){
  
  var button = $('#back-to-top');
  
  button.click(function(){
   
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 600);
   
  });
  
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Tabs */
 function tabsOn(){
  
  $('.tabs').each(function(){
   
   var tab = $(this);
   tab.find('.tab-content > div').hide();
   tab.find('.tab-heading>a:first-child').addClass('active');
   tab.find('.tab-content > div:first-child').show();
   
   var tabMenuItems = tab.find('.tab-heading>a');
   tabMenuItems.click(function(e){
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    
    tab.find('.tab-content > div').hide();
    tab.find('.tab-heading>a').removeClass('active');
    
    $(this).addClass('active');
    tab.find(target).show();
    
   });
   
  });
   
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Accordions */
 function accordionsOn(){
  
  $('.accordion').each(function(){
   
   var accordion = $(this);
   accordion.find('.accordion-content').hide();
   accordion.find('>ul>li:first-child').addClass('accordion-active').find('.accordion-content').show();
   accordion.find('.accordion-header').click(function(){
    
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('accordion-active')){
     $(this).parent().removeClass('accordion-active');
     $(this).parent().find('.accordion-content').slideUp(300);
    }else{
     $(this).parent().parent().find('li.accordion-active').removeClass('accordion-active').find('.accordion-content').slideUp(300);
     $(this).parent().addClass('accordion-active').find('.accordion-content').slideDown(300)
    }
    
   });
   
  });
  
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Select Box Styles */
 function selectBox(){
 
  var config = {
    '.chosen-select'           : {disable_search_threshold:10},
    '.chosen-select-full-width'           : {disable_search_threshold:10, width:'100%'},
    '.chosen-select-search' : {disable_search_threshold:10, width:'100%'}
  }
  for (var selector in config) {
    $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
  }
  
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Wuick View */
 function quickViewModal(el){
  
  $('body').append('<div id="quick-view-modal"><div id="quick-view-content"><div id="quick-view-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div class="quick-view-content"><div class="quick-view-container col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"></div></div></div></div>');
  $('#quick-view-modal').hide();
  
  $('#quick-view-close').click(function(){
   
   $('#quick-view-modal').fadeOut(300);
   
  });
  
  /* Scroll Bar */
  $('.quick-view-content').perfectScrollbar({wheelSpeed: 40, suppressScrollX:true});
  
  var elements = el;
  elements.click(function(e){
  
   e.preventDefault();
   var target = $(this).attr('href');
   
   $('#quick-view-content .quick-view-container').load(target+' #product-single', function(){
    
    
    /* Rating Box */
    $('#quick-view-modal .rating.readonly-rating').raty({ readOnly: true, path:'js/img',score: function() {
     return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }});
    $('#quick-view-modal .rating.rate').raty({ path:'js/img',score: function() {
     return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }});
    
    
    /* Accordions */
    var productButtons = $('#quick-view-content .product-actions').not('.full-width');
    productButtons.find('>span:first-child').addClass('current');
    
    productButtons.find('>span').hover(function(){
     
     $(this).parent().find('>span').removeClass('current');
     $(this).addClass('current');
     
    }, function(){
     
     $(this).removeClass('current');
     
    });
    
    productButtons.hover(function(){
     
    }, function(){
     $(this).find('>span:first-child').addClass('current');
    });
    
    
    /* Tabs */
    tabsOn();
    
    /* Numeric Input */
    $('#quick-view-modal .numeric-input').each(function(){
  
     var el = $(this);
     numericInput(el);
     
    });
    
    /* Char Counter */
    $('#quick-view-modal .char-counter').each(function(){
     
     var el = $(this);
     charCounter(el);
     
    });
    
    
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    
    
    /* Product Carousel */
    $('#quick-view-modal #product-carousel').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
     controlNav: false,
     animationLoop: false,
     directionNav: false,
     slideshow: false,
     itemWidth: 80,
     itemMargin: 0,
     start: function(slider){
       setActive($('#product-carousel li:first-child img'));
       slider.find('.right-arrow').click(function(){
        slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("next"));
       });
       slider.find('.left-arrow').click(function(){
        slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("prev"));
       });
       slider.find('img').click(function(){
        var large = $(this).attr('data-large');
        setActive($(this));
        $('#product-slider img').fadeOut(300, changeImg(large, $('#product-slider img')));
       });
       function changeImg(large, element){
        var element = element;
        var large = large;
        setTimeout(function(){ startF()},300);
        function startF(){
         element.attr('src', large)
         element.attr('data-large', large)
         element.fadeIn(300);
        }
        
       }
       function setActive(el){
        var element = el;
        $('#product-carousel img').removeClass('active-item');
        element.addClass('active-item');
       }
      }
    });
    
    $('#quick-view-modal').fadeIn(300);
    
    
    /* Positioning */
    var q_width = $('#quick-view-content').width();
    var q_height = $('#quick-view-content').height();
    var q_margin = ($(window).height() - q_height)/2;
    
    $('#quick-view-content').css('margin-top',q_margin+'px');
    
    
    /* Cloud Zoom */
    $("#quick-view-modal .cloud-zoom").imagezoomsl({
      zoomrange: [3, 3]
      });
    
    $('.quick-view-content').perfectScrollbar('update');
    $('.quick-view-content').css('overflow','hidden');
    
    $('.quick-view-content').click(function(){
     $(this).perfectScrollbar('update');
    });
    
    /* Select Box */
    var config = {
     '#quick-view-content .chosen-select' : {disable_search_threshold:10}
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
    
   });
   
  });
  
 }
 
 
 
 
 /* AJAX FORMS */
 
 /* Newsletter */
 
 $('#newsletter').submit(function(e){
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var url = $(this).attr('action');
  
  if($(this).find('input[type="text"]').val() == ''){
   
   if($(this).find('span.error').length==0){
    $(this).append('<span class="error">Please, fill in your email address</span>');
   }else{
    $(this).find('span.error').text('Please, fill in your email address');
   }
   
  }else{
   
   $(this).find('span.error').hide();
   
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $('#newsletter').serialize(), 
    success: function(data){
       $('#newsletter').find('>*').slideUp(300);
       $('#newsletter').append('<span>'+data+'</span>');
    }
   });
  }
  
 });
 
 
 /* Contact Form */
 
 $('#contact-form').submit(function(e){
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var url = $(this).attr('action');
  var error = false;
  
  if($(this).find('input[name="contact-name"]').val()==''){
   error = true;
  }
  
  if($(this).find('input[name="contact-email"]').val()==''){
   error = true;
  }
  
  if($(this).find('textarea[name="contact-message"]').val()==''){
   error = true;
  }
  
  if(error == true){
   
   if($(this).find('span.error').length==0){
    $(this).append('<span class="error">Please, fill in all the fields</span>');
   }else{
    $(this).find('span.error').text('Please, fill in all the fields');
   }
   
  }
  
  if(error == false){ 
   $(this).find('span.error').hide();
   
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $('#contact-form').serialize(), 
    success: function(data){
       $('#contact-form').find('>*').slideUp(300);
       $('#contact-form').append('<span>'+data+'</span>');
    }
   });
  }
  
 });
 
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Numeric Input */
 $('.numeric-input').each(function(){
  
  var el = $(this);
  numericInput(el);
  
 });
 
 
 /* Numeric Input */
 function numericInput(el){
  
  var element = el;
  var input = $(element).find('input');
  
  $(element).find('.arrow-up').click(function(){
   var value = parseInt(input.val());
   input.val(value+1);
  });
  
  $(element).find('.arrow-down').click(function(){
   var value = parseInt(input.val());
   input.val(value-1);
  });
  
  input.keypress(function(e){
   
   var value = parseInt(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
   if(isNaN(value)){
    e.preventDefault();
   }
   
  });
  
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 /* Char Counter */
 $('.char-counter').each(function(){
  
  var el = $(this);
  charCounter(el);
  
 });
 
 
 function charCounter(el){
  
  var element = el;
  var counter = $(element).find('input');
  var target = $(counter).attr('data-target');
  
  $(target).bind("change paste keyup",function(){
   
   var value = $(this).val();
   var length = value.length;
   
   counter.val(length);
   
  });
  
 }
 
 
});
//quick view ends
```

```html
<div id="productContainer">
   <div align="center" class="product-layout product-grid col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 product-image"><div class="product">
  <div class="product-image">
    <img src="../image/product/MUKESH KAUSHIK.JPG" class="img-responsive" style="width:250px;height:200px;">
    <a href="products_view.php?id=30" class="product-hover" style="width:100%;"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Quick View</a></div><div class="caption"><h4>TAta 407</h4><p class="price"><span class="price-new"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp;1000&nbsp;</span></p>
  </div>
  </div>  
   </div>
```